# Identify this LED

Tags: led

I am trying to identify this LED Brand.  It is not on Newark or Digikey.
Anyone have an idea?
Dimensions are approximately 2.75 mm x 3.5 mm x 1.8 mm
Color is white.
Where else could I search for it besides Digikey and Newark? Thanks

[image: Unknown LED]

[image: LED]

Comment: *Blue Osram TOPLED, White Osram Power TOPLED* or some clone of it.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks Janka!  I have been looking on and off for weeks!  I should have just asked!

Comment: no, you were right to do research before asking ... +1 for doing that

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it at D-K 1st attempt by using the metric size
2.75 mm x 3.5 mm  = 35xx or xx35
[image]
Looks square 3535 ?? hmm

https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/vishay-semiconductor-opto-division/VLMW51Q2R3-GS08/3748976

[My 2nd attempt now using the filter 2835 + SMD + white = looks better for size](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/led-lighting-white/124?s=N4IgjCBcoGwJxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAA4AuUIAyiQE4CWAdgOYiED2UA2iACwAMcAZkEgAugF9CYAExwI0ECkgYcBYmUiUaDZm07gY3AOwwBoiSAC0UxAqg0ArqtLkWIdpC4BWM%2BeseQ2AC2ACYABJi4YQDuABa0JLiihN7yRFBghERpkFKeYmJAA)

Besides Case Size, you also need to know some optical parameters.

Any questions?